# Can vertex indices be transferred between identical meshes?

Tags: vertices, shape-keys

I want to transfer the vertex indices from one mesh, to another mesh with identical topology, shape, size ect. As an example, I created two identical subdivided cubes. The only difference is that they do not have the same vertex indices.[image: Two identical cubes.]
To demonstrate the problem I am having, I sculpted some smiley faces on to the cubes as shape keys.[image: Some smiley face shape keys as examples.]
My goal is to have both shape keys applied to one cube at the same time. However, when I try to copy the shape key from the red cube to the green one, it doesn't work. I have tried Transfer Shape Key (left), which doesn't apply correctly. I have also tried Join as Shapes (right), which heavily distorts the cube.[image: Failed shape key transfers due to different vertex indices.]
Is there a way I can change the vertex indices of the cube red cube to match the cube on the right?

Comment: Danny Mac talks about this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTgSLYY9uew and links to the source of an addon here: https://gumroad.com/bartoszstyperek?sort=page_layout&tags=addons#qhrJ

Comment: @R-800 Thank you that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missunderstanding what you are trying to do here, wouldn't just making a copy of the Green cube in object mode be the easiest way to insure that both objects have identical vertex indices?

I thought it would be possible to **Transfer Mesh Data** from Green to Red cube. **Object** menu > **Relations** > **Transform Mesh Data** but I couldn't get it to work.

Tried with the **Data Transfer modifier** but again with no success.

That left the long way of transferring vertex indices :
Link the data of the Red to the Green and then remove the link.

[image]

In **Object** mode first select Red object then select the Green one. **Object menu** > **Make Links** > **Object Data**.
[image]

The Red object now has the same vertex order as the Green object: 
[image]

......... but also using all other data from the Green object. 
The Red can be unlinked in the **Object Data Properties** menu:
[image]

There must be a more elegant way of doing this  :)

```
there you go ... an Addon, see comment above.  Thankyou  @R-800  :)
```

Comment: My goal was to apply the shape key of the red cube to the green cube, or visa versa. The problem I have with the linking method is that it erases the shape key of the red cube.

Answer (score 0):

To copy the vertex order from one mesh to another, you can use this free addon. [original](https://bartoszstyperek.gumroad.com/l/copy_verts_ids), [mirror](https://github.com/hannesdelbeke/transfer_vertex_order)

#### install addon

1. Install it to your addons folder
2. go to preferences/add-ons and search for "transfer vertex order".
3. Enable the addon.

#### use addon

1. select mesh1 (source) and mesh2 (target)
2. In your 3d viewport, press N to show the sidebar & click the tools tab
3. click transfer vertex order button in the tool.

##### requirements

Works for blender 2.8+. Tested in Blender 3.3 and still works.

PS: The answer was already in @R-800's comment. But posting this as an answer since I missed it and found the same answer myself on Google.

Comment: I just tried this in 3.6 using the UV option (I had a base mesh that I modified to create a morph, but forgot to apply subsurf and solidify modifiers so the vertex orders got jacked up) and it did NOT work.